# How to backup a compressed version of your raspberry pi sd card image on Windows 10?

Tags: raspbian-buster, image, backup

I'm interested in backing up my hard work and time invested RPi image with all packages setting and files installed in there and put it on a RPi zero w from RPi 4B so I've seen this thread on the stack so I did it but here is the problem:

Using a 128GB card this created a file of this size on the image and it's problematic to move it to other SD cards.

How'd you backup an image and have it compressed to it's minimum size?

Comment: Compression will only shrink the image - not let you put it on smaller cards as it will be expended back.  Have you tried Etcher as it can cope with different sized cards?  You could also try gparted and shrink the card partitions before using the imager. Also look at https://www.pibakery.org/index.html

Comment: So well etcher doesn't work and the problem is that I'm running windows but I do have linux VM but when I connect the reader with the SD the drive only shows on windows and won't appear no idea on how to use linux that much as I'm a noob there.

Comment: I don't know if you will find proper applications to shrink and copy a RaspiOS SD image using MS Windows. With an additional spare SD Card you could use the RasPi itself to do it. But that wasn't ask...

Answer (score 2):

Install EXT4 plugins in windows . Make sure your PC is free from virus. Then connect the card and copy everything. You can enter rootfs directly with this.

Comment: But how does the images already being compressed before moving to the target's memory?